I want to find a method to avoid complexity and coupling in django models + rest api
I created a model for an API. After that, I planned to add more APIs from different platforms. however, all of the APIs were for the same purpose but the data they required and their methods of accepting the data differ.
For example. (it's just an example to explain, not the actual case but 90% similar)
I create a model with attributes (name, email, password), but the second API is using (firstname, lastname, email, password). Maybe the third API will ask for (Surname, country, oassword) etc.
Then I wanted to create a view to perform CRUD operation. But to know which crud should be done for which API, I created a class with the name CRUD handler in which the class will specify which one to use.
I also created another class with the name 'BOT' which had a unique secret key to identify which user wants to use which API. So that every time the credentials are not meant to be sent for safety.
Almost all of them use/support the REST framework
This is the flow that I want:
some_other_WEbsite -> (sends data with secret key) -> djangoview -> BOT ->(uses secret key) to identify the USER, the API -> uses function to perform any CRUD operation.
The issue is:
if I add (name, firstname, lastname, surname, country, email, password) as attributes in a single model, the model will use more space, conditions will increase etc.
Is there something that I can do to handle that complexity? Any suggestion is appreciated.
For now, I created different models with different attributes for the relative API like
API1 = name, email, password
API2 = firstname, lastname, email, password
API3 = Surname, country, password
modified the BOT as:
BOT = botname, unique_secret_key, API1, API2, API3.
After doing that, technically speaking the User can add 3 APIs in 1 bot, except I don't allow it from the front-end,  which I don't want to create confusion or to increase if/else conditions. like he can accidentally add the details of API1 in API2 fields or something else.

As somebody who's done this "ifs in a view" scheme, except with normal views, I'd just advise against it and instead break them up into different views. Especially with DRF, this is more OpenApi supported and generally it's the standard. Per the model end of it, you have multiple directions: make separate models, model inheritance or ForignKey extra attributes (~ApiOneUser.User -> BaseUser)
